# Problem opening a virtual MIDI Input in IOS with AudioKit MIDI

Tags: ios, audiokit

Having a problem setting up a virtual MIDI input port that shows up on other apps. I'm probably just leaving out something here. MIDI, in general, has been working great using an external midi port from the camera kit. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

```
private let midi = AudioKit.midi
midi.createVirtualInputPort(487394857, name: "my virtual input")
midi.openInput(name: "my virtual input")
midi.addListener(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabled audio in background modes in the app capabilities. Now shows up on other apps port lists and is able to receive MIDI notes. I think this can cause problems with app approval. I don't think Apple will allow this to be enabled unless the app is a music player.